# Interpolating along a table of values

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I have a dataframe with 5 columns (a, b, c, d, e, f). I then have specific values for columns a, b and c and need to interpolate along the dataframe to get values for columns d and e as well.

As a simplified case I try to do e.g.:

```
a = np.array(random.sample(range(1, 1001), 100)) 
b = 2* a
c = 3* a 
d = 4* a 
e= 5* a 

data = {'a': a,
        'b': b,
        'c': c,
        'd': d,
        'e': e}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

to_interp = {'a': [200.0, 525.0],
             'b': [400.0, 1050.0],
             'c': [600.0, 1575.0]}


new_df = pd.DataFrame(to_interp)

df = pd.concat([df, new_df], ignore_index=True)

df.sort_values('a', inplace=True)

df['d'] = df['d'].interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0) 

df['e'] = df['e'].interpolate(method='linear', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)

interpolated_values = df[df['a'].isin(to_interp['a'])][['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']].copy()

print(interpolated_values)
```

but for this simplified case I am getting

```
        a, b, c, d, e = 

 200.0 ,  400.0,   600.0 ,  800.0 , 1000.0

 525.0,  1050.0  ,1575.0 , 2106.0 , 2632.5
```

which doesn't look right when i look at the row defined by a=525.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: welcome to SO. read following notice for you : [mre] Do not make the example unnecessarily long. **It will be difficult to get an answer.** Also, if you create a random sample, you need to provide the seed.

Comment: Additionally, you can find your wrong by [reading the official documentation of interpolate function.](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) Not only interpolate function, but all functions that are applied to a series in all Pandas functions only work within the series. This means that **series cannot use axis=0.**

Answer (score 0):

You should fix `random.seed(0)` and provide the exact expected output for clarity, but I imagine that you need to might want to interpolate relative to `a` (in which case, set it as index and use `method='index'`.

Then, [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html) and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
tmp = (pd.concat([df, new_df], ignore_index=True)
         .sort_values('a').set_index('a')
         .interpolate(method='index', limit_direction='forward', axis=0)
         .reset_index()
      )

out = new_df.combine_first(new_df[['a']].merge(tmp, how='left'))
```

Output (using `random.seed(0)` to define the input):

```
       a       b       c       d       e
0  200.0   400.0   600.0   800.0  1000.0
1  525.0  1050.0  1575.0  2100.0  2625.0
```